# dired-read-file-name: pop-up dired mode to read-file-name

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

Could anyone please give me a hand to briefly pop-up a dired buffer for the purposes of `read-file-name`:

```
(defun dired-insert-file ()
  (interactive)
  (setq filename (dired-read-file-name "~/Desktop"))
  (kill-buffer dired)
  (get-buffer-create "*foo*")
  (set-buffer "*foo*")
  (insert-file filename))
```

---

**EDIT**:  Revised example:

```
(require 'dired)

(defvar open-with-variable nil)
(defvar save-as-variable nil)
(defvar save-as-buffer-filename nil)

(defun dired-read-file-name (&optional directory)
  (let* (
      output-filename
      (working-buffer (buffer-name)))
    (if directory
      (dired directory)
    (dired nil))
    (if save-as-buffer-filename
      (progn
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (re-search-forward (file-name-nondirectory save-as-buffer-filename) nil t)))
    (recursive-edit)
    (switch-to-buffer working-buffer)
    output-filename))

(defun dired-insert-file ()
(interactive)
  (let* (
    (save-as-variable t)
    (lawlist-filename (dired-read-file-name)))
    (insert-file-contents lawlist-filename)))

;; Open with external application.
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-c o") (lambda () (interactive)
  (let* (
      (open-with-variable t)
      (lawlist-filename (dired-get-file-for-visit))
      (application (dired-read-file-name "/Applications")))
  (start-process "external-application" nil "open" "-a" application lawlist-filename))))

(defun lawlist-save-as ()
(interactive)
  (let* (
      save-as-filename
      (save-as-variable t)
      (save-as-buffer-filename (if (buffer-file-name) (buffer-file-name)))
      (proposed-filename (dired-read-file-name)))
    (when proposed-filename ;; needed if aborting recursive-edit
      (setq save-as-filename (read-string "Save-As:  "
        (if (file-directory-p proposed-filename)
          (concat proposed-filename (buffer-name))
          proposed-filename)))
      (when (and save-as-filename (file-exists-p save-as-filename))
        (or (y-or-n-p (format "File `%s' exists; overwrite? " save-as-filename))
          (error "Canceled")))
      (set-visited-file-name save-as-filename)
      (set-buffer-modified-p t)
      (and (buffer-file-name)
           (file-writable-p buffer-file-name)
           (setq buffer-read-only nil))
      (save-buffer))))

;; delete the buffer after selecting file | application | directory
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<return>") (lambda () (interactive)
  (select-file-application-directory t)))

;; do not delete the buffer after selecting file | application | directory
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<C-M-s-return>") (lambda () (interactive)
  (select-file-application-directory nil)))

;; select file | application | directory
(defun select-file-application-directory (&optional delete-buffer)
  (let* (
    (fn-list (dired-get-marked-files))
    (rfn-list (mapcar (function dired-make-relative) fn-list))
    (dired-one-file (and (consp fn-list) (null (cdr fn-list)) (car fn-list)))
    (input-filename (if dired-one-file dired-one-file fn-list))
    (ext
      (cond
        ((stringp input-filename)
          (file-name-extension input-filename))
        ((listp input-filename)
          (file-name-extension (car input-filename)))))
    (path (if (stringp input-filename) (file-name-directory input-filename)))
    (dired-buffer-name (buffer-name))
    (msword "/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word")
    (ooo "/Applications/OpenOffice.org.app")
    (excel "/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Excel.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Excel")
    (adobe "/Applications/Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro/Adobe Acrobat Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/AdobeAcrobat")
    (preview "/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview")
    (skim "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/MacOS/Skim")
    (input-regexp '("odt" "wpd" "docx" "doc" "xls" "pdf" "tif" "bmp" "jpg"))
    (pdf-regexp '("pdf" "tif" "bmp" "jpg"))
    (ooo-regexp '("odt" "wpd"))
    (msword-regexp '("doc" "docx")))
  (cond
    ;; only use current path a save-as situation.
    ((and
        (equal input-filename (concat path "."))
        save-as-variable)
      (setq output-filename (expand-file-name default-directory))
      (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name))
      (throw 'exit nil))
    ;; save-as (stringp) | dired-insert-file
    ((and
        (stringp input-filename)
        (not (file-directory-p input-filename))
        (file-exists-p input-filename)
        (not (equal input-filename (concat path ".")))
        save-as-variable)
      (setq output-filename input-filename)
      (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name))
      (throw 'exit nil))
    ;; open just one file, except input-regexp
    ((and
        (stringp input-filename)
        (not (file-directory-p input-filename))
        (file-exists-p input-filename)
        (not (equal input-filename (concat path ".")))
        (not save-as-variable)
        (not (regexp-match-p input-regexp ext)))
      (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name))
      (find-file input-filename))
    ;; open numerous files, except input-regexp
    ((and
        (listp input-filename)
        (not (regexp-match-p input-regexp ext)))
      (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name))
      (mapc 'find-file input-filename))
    ;; open OpenOfficeOrg
    ((and
        (stringp input-filename)
        (not (file-directory-p input-filename))
        (file-exists-p input-filename)
        (not (equal input-filename (concat path ".")))
        (not save-as-variable)
        (regexp-match-p ooo-regexp ext))
      (start-process "ooo-view" nil "open" "-a" ooo input-filename)
      (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
    ;; open msword
    ((and
        (stringp input-filename)
        (not (file-directory-p input-filename))
        (file-exists-p input-filename)
        (not (equal input-filename (concat path ".")))
        (not save-as-variable)
        (regexp-match-p msword-regexp ext))
      (start-process "msword-view" nil "open" "-a" msword input-filename)
      (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
    ;; open excel
    ((and
        (stringp input-filename)
        (not (file-directory-p input-filename))
        (file-exists-p input-filename)
        (not (equal input-filename (concat path ".")))
        (not save-as-variable)
        (equal ext "xls"))
      (start-process "excel-view" nil "open" "-a" excel input-filename)
      (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
    ;; *.pdf -- open just one *.pdf file.
    ((and
        (stringp input-filename)
        (not (file-directory-p input-filename))
        (file-exists-p input-filename)
        (not (equal input-filename (concat path ".")))
        (not save-as-variable)
        (regexp-match-p pdf-regexp ext))
      (lawlist-message "[a]dobe | [p]review | [s]kim")
      (let* ((select-pdf-viewer (read-char-exclusive)))
        (cond
          ((eq select-pdf-viewer ?a)
            (start-process "pdf-with-adobe" nil "open" "-a" adobe input-filename)
            (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
          ((eq select-pdf-viewer ?p)
            (start-process "pdf-with-preview" nil "open" "-a" preview input-filename)
            (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
          ((eq select-pdf-viewer ?s)
            (start-process "pdf-with-adobe" nil "open" "-a" skim input-filename)
            (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
          (t (message "You have exited the sub-function.")) )) )
    ;; *.pdf -- open more than just one *.pdf file.
    ((and
        (listp input-filename)
        (not save-as-variable)
        (regexp-match-p pdf-regexp ext))
      (lawlist-message "[a]dobe | [p]review | [s]kim")
      (let* ((select-pdf-viewer (read-char-exclusive)))
        (cond
          ((eq select-pdf-viewer ?a)
            (mapcar (lambda (x)
              (start-process "pdf-with-adobe" nil "open" "-a" adobe x) )
                input-filename)
            (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
          ((eq select-pdf-viewer ?p)
            (mapcar (lambda (x)
              (start-process "pdf-with-preview" nil "open" "-a" preview x) )
                input-filename)
            (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
          ((eq select-pdf-viewer ?s)
            (mapcar (lambda (x)
              (start-process "pdf-with-adobe" nil "open" "-a" skim x) )
                input-filename)
            (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
          (t (message "You have exited the sub-function.")) )) )
    ;; open with external application, because the `open-with-variable` is t.
    ((and
        open-with-variable
        (equal ext "app"))
      (setq output-filename input-filename)
      (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name))
      (throw 'exit nil))
    ;; Enter the directory; or, open an application
    ((and
        (file-directory-p input-filename)
        (not (equal input-filename (concat path ".")))
        (not open-with-variable))
      (if (equal ext "app")
        (progn
          (message "[d]eeper | [o]pen")
          (let* ((deeper-open (read-char-exclusive)))
            (cond
              ((eq deeper-open ?d)
                (dired-find-file)
                (goto-char (point-min))
                (re-search-forward " \\.\\.$" nil t)
                (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
              ((eq deeper-open ?o)
                (start-process "application" nil "open" "-a" input-filename)
                (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))
              (t (message "You have exited the sub-function.")) )) )
        (dired-find-file)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (re-search-forward " \\.\\.$" nil t)
        (if delete-buffer (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)))) )))

;; https://github.com/kentaro/auto-save-buffers-enhanced
;; `regexp-match-p` function modified by @sds on stackoverflow
;; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343048/distinguishing-files-with-extensions-from-hidden-files-and-no-extensions
(defun regexp-match-p (regexps string)
  (and string
       (catch 'matched
         (let ((inhibit-changing-match-data t)) ; small optimization
           (dolist (regexp regexps)
             (when (string-match regexp string)
               (throw 'matched t)))))))

(defun lawlist-message (input)
(interactive)
  (message
    (propertize input 'face 'font-lock-warning-face)))
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you really want -- what problem you are trying to solve. If you just want a command that reads a file name and then inserts the file, why fiddle with Dired? Sounds like we're missing some other requirement. (See [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/231821).)

Comment: I was interested in using Dired to read a file name, instead of other methods (like `ns-read-file-name`), and I came up with `(setq filename (car (dired-get-marked-files)))`.  However, that requires a multi-step approach -- i.e., open up a Dired buffer, move the cursor to the desired file, and then run the insert file command.  So, I was trying to think of a way to combine everything into one function with a pause to permit me to select the file.  However, `read-event` won't let me move the cursor up / down the Dired buffer to select the file and then proceed to the next step of the function.

Comment: Maybe you want `expand-file-name`? But I think that `insert-file` expands it anyway... I mean, even if your code worked, with or without the third line it'd do the same thing. Also, instead of the combo of `get-buffer-creat`, `set-buffer`, `insert-file` you can just use `find-file-literally`. I think that's exactly what it does. Also, you don't want to use `insert-file`, probably, `insert-file-contents`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want "Dired to read a file name", instead of just using `read-file-name`? Sorry, I don't get the connection with Dired from your description of how this would be used.

Comment: `dired-read-file-name` is just an alternative I was interested in exploring instead of `read-file-name` or `ns-read-file-name`, and I wanted to learn how to accomplish that objective using Emacs Lisp.  It seemed to me that someone probably had invented this function a long time ago, and I thought perhaps it would be a quick solution.  I'm really surprised it doesn't exist yet.  At the ultimate conclusion of this thread, the function will exist -- and others will not spend an hour (like myself) Googling to find a function they think might already exist.  `Stefan` has given me a strong hint :) .

Comment: Well, this function only has meaning in the context of `dired` because it's an internal function which assumes a lot about how it is called, what is currently in the buffer and more yet, it deals with, for example, marks, the current directory (in dired buffer) etc. I still think that you would be better off explaining what is the end result instead of what functions you want to use because as of now the end result is very strange.

Comment: I've updated my question to include a first working draft of the concept `dired-read-file-name`.  It uses `recursive-edit` as suggested by @Stefan.  I still haven't found a way to incorporate `catch` / `throw`, but perhaps that is not needed.  I also used `insert-file-contents` instead of `insert-file` as suggested by @wvxvw.

Comment: 1) You really don't want to use `get-buffer-create` in this situation, use some macro, maybe `(with-current-buffer "*foo*" (insert-file-contents ...))`. 2) Do I understand it correctly that you wanted to create a buffer with the contents of a file, however, not bound to that file, s.t. if you eg. try to save it, it will not know where to save it? What would you do later with this file / text buffer?

Comment: Point well taken -- thank you -- I've updated the working draft, which makes more sense now for a situation when inserting a file.  I will ultimately be using the function to access a form file directory (e.g. templates) -- one option will be to insert a file, and another option will be to open the file -- both using the dired concept.

Comment: Okay, I think that's a wrap -- the updated third draft is working as I had hoped.  Thank you everyone for helping me to bring to fruition the concept of `dired-read-file-name`.

Comment: You can use `(case character (?a <do stuff if a>) (?b ...) (otherwise ...))` instead of using `cond` (it is shorter, requires `cl`). :)

Comment: @wvxvw Thank you for the alternative method of writing the code -- greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to look into `recursive-edit`: pop up a dired buffer in which you add a way to *exit* (which works by performing a `(throw 'exit <value>)`), and then call `(recursive-edit)` which will return the `<value>` passed to `throw`.

Comment: Thank you for broadening my horizons with `recursive-edit` -- greatly appreciated !!!  :)