# define keybinding for dired to run a command ("open ") on the file under the cursor

Tags: macos, emacs, elisp, dired

I want to stop using finder in OSX and use dired instead. OSX has a command, "open ", to open any file in the default app from the cli. (Example: "open $the_file"). This works fine with C-! followed by me entering "open " but I'd like to do both those thing with a key combination, say C-0.

How can I create a function that does the equivalent of "C-!" -> "open " in dired when I press C-0 with the cursor over a filepath?

(EDIT: I found a solution, macros!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reset `lawlist-filename` to `nil` at the end of each example so that it can be used in a variety of other functions, including, but not limited to, `dired-read-file-name`:  [dired-read-file-name: pop-up dired mode to read-file-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899595/dired-read-file-name-pop-up-dired-mode-to-read-file-name)

EDIT:  Rewritten with the help of @phils -- uses `let` bindings, instead of global variables.

```
(eval-after-load "dired" '(progn

  ;; open anything externally with OSX default app -- Wide-Open-Throttle!
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "z") (lambda () (interactive)
    (let ((lawlist-filename (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
      (start-process "default-app" nil "open" lawlist-filename))))

  ;; open *.pdf file externally with the OSX default *.pdf viewer.
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<SPC>") (lambda () (interactive)
    (let ((lawlist-filename (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
      (if (equal (file-name-extension lawlist-filename) "pdf")
        (start-process "default-pdf-app" nil "open" lawlist-filename)))))

  ;; open *.pdf file externally using Skim.
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "v") (lambda () (interactive)
    (let* (
      (lawlist-filename (dired-get-file-for-visit))
      (skim "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/MacOS/Skim") )
      (if (equal (file-name-extension lawlist-filename) "pdf")
        (start-process "pdf-with-skim" nil "open" "-a" skim lawlist-filename)))))

))
```

Comment: Thanks! With the open command I trust osx to handle anything, it's basically the cli version of a double click. That might be wrong though.

Comment: The second example is a way of specifying what application you want to use, e.g., Skim instead of the default viewer Adobe.

Comment: Maybe you could add a piece of code that uses just the open command and would work on any file? I think it's safe to use it, and possibly more convenient: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html

Comment: For convenience of anyone reading this: "The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had double-clicked the file's icon. If no application name is specified, the default application as determined via LaunchServices is used to open the specified files."

Comment: The first example `<SPC>` uses just the `open` command; however, there are a number of situations where you may want to limit what types of files can be opened externally -- so I prefer to use certain file extensions as a limiting factor.  In the first example, you could remove the limiting factor by deleting `(if (equal (file-name-extension lawlist-filename) "pdf") (start-process "open-externally" nil "open" lawlist-filename))` and replacing it with `(start-process "open-externally" nil "open" lawlist-filename)`.

Comment: I tried, got this error message, probably me messing up the indentation/syntax: progn: Wrong number of arguments: define-key, 4

Comment: (eval-after-load "dired" '(progn

  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<SPC>") (lambda () (interactive)
    (setq lawlist-filename (car (dired-get-marked-files)))
        (start-process "open-externally" nil "open" lawlist-filename))
    (setq lawlist-filename nil) ))
))

Comment: I added the *wide open throttle* example.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not let-binding your filename variable?

Comment: That is a very good point -- especially since I have recently spent a lot of time trying to set variables back to `nil` at the end of my functions.  I'll put this project on my todo-list -- which will include revamping many of my functions where I've been reusing the same variable name and having problems when a value is left over from a prior function.  You just turned on a light bulb inside my head -- thanks :)

Comment: @phils  I have not been able to figure out how to use `let` bindings for variables within `start-process` and/or within a keyboard shortcut definition.  It is possible to use `(dired-get-file-for-visit)` within the `start-process` command *instead of* a pre-defined variable.  However, the path to an external application would either need to be stored as a global variable or spelled out entirely within the `start-process` command.  Although not applicable here, the entire `start-process` command cannot be `let` bound when using `set-process-sentinel` because `start-process` runs immediately.

Comment: Certainly process sentinels have other requirements, but in these instances every initial `(setq lawlist-filename` can be replaced with `(let ((lawlist-filename` (and appropriate balancing at the end of the function), and the final setq removed.

Comment: @phils Thank you very much for helping me get the correct format for the `let` bindings -- I was missing a pair of parenthesis in my tests.  I've updated the code in the answer, and I'll be using it as a guide to replace many of the global variables in my personal configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it seems inelegant:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros

I used a macro:

> (fset 'my_macro

```
[?! ?o ?p ?e ?n ?  return])
```