# Distinguishing files with extensions, from hidden files and no extensions

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

I'm having difficulty distinguishing files *with* extensions, from files *without* extensions, and  *hidden* files.  I'm using `(file-name-extension (dired-get-file-for-visit))` in dired-mode, and the type of file extension determines what action to take -- e.g., open in Emacs, or open externally with a particular application.

A hidden file (e.g., `.hidden`) returns a value of `nil` instead of `"hidden"`.

A file with *no extension* (e.g., `foo`) also returns a value of `nil`.

Can anyone suggest an alternative method to handle this?

```
(let* (
    (input-regexp '("odt" "wpd" "docx" "doc" "xls" "pdf" "tif" "bmp" "jpg"))
    (input-filename (dired-get-file-for-visit)) )
  (if (not (regexp-match-p input-regexp (file-name-extension input-filename))))
    (find-file input-filename) )

;; https://github.com/kentaro/auto-save-buffers-enhanced
(defun regexp-match-p (regexps string)
  (catch 'matched
    (dolist (regexp regexps)
      (if (string-match regexp string)
        (throw 'matched t)))))
```

Here is the debugger (partial):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  string-match("odt" nil)
  (if (string-match regexp string) (throw (quote matched) t))
  (while --dolist-tail-- (setq regexp (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (string-match regexp string) (throw (quote matched) t)) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--)))
  (let ((--dolist-tail-- regexps) regexp) (while --dolist-tail-- (setq regexp (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (string-match regexp string) (throw (quote matched) t)) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--))))
  (progn (let ((--dolist-tail-- regexps) regexp) (while --dolist-tail-- (setq regexp (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (string-match regexp string) (throw (quote matched) t)) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--)))))
  (catch (quote matched) (progn (let ((--dolist-tail-- regexps) regexp) (while --dolist-tail-- (setq regexp (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (string-match regexp string) (throw (quote matched) t)) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--))))))
  regexp-match-p(("odt" "wpd" "docx" "doc" "xls" "pdf" "tif" "bmp" "jpg") nil)
  (not (regexp-match-p input-regexp (file-name-extension input-filename)))
***
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
(let* ((input-regexp '("odt" "wpd" "docx" "doc" "xls" "pdf" "tif" "bmp" "jpg"))
       (input-filename (dired-get-file-for-visit))
       (ext (file-name-extension input-filename)))
  (unless (and ext (regexp-match-p input-regexp ext))
    (find-file input-filename)))
```

Alternatively, redefine

```
(defun regexp-match-p (regexps string)
  (and string
       (catch 'matched
         (let ((inhibit-changing-match-data t)) ; small optimization
           (dolist (regexp regexps)
             (when (string-match regexp string)
               (throw 'matched t)))))))
```

Comment: Both of your solutions work.  I've added your redefined function to my bag of goodies.  Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use `string-match-p` instead of `string-match`, since you do not use the match data.