# emacs/elisp select file with dired/file dialog, then perform an operation?

Tags: emacs, dired

I want to write code so that the use can select a file for an operation using dired or some other file dialog, NOT the minibuffer. Eg he invokes a "Get files statistics" command, dired comes up, he chooses, and the stats appear. (This becomes much more interesting find-dired.)

But the two ways I can see of doing this - launching a dired with an altered keymap so that selecting a file invokes a fn to finish the command, and supplying after advice to dired-find-file - seem odd for what I thought would be a common task. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you looking for a function like `dired-get-file-for-visit`, which gets the file/directory name at point, or `dired-get-marked-files`, which will get the file/directory names underneath point of all marked files/directories -- it returns a list?  To be truthful, your question is somewhat unclear -- perhaps you should consider clarifying it a bit.

Comment: The following link is a custom version of the concept that I call `dired-read-file-name` -- http://stackoverflow.com/q/19899595/2112489  Perhaps that is the concept you are searching for?  It uses `recursive-edit` when popping open a dired buffer to select files/directories.  I do the same thing for a custom `tree-view` mode of files/directories.

Answer (score 2):

Why not leave popping-up Dired out of it, and let users do that themselves?

Just bind a key in `dired-mode-map` that acts on the marked files (or the current file if none marked), performing whatever action you like (e.g., show stats).

That's the typical Dired approach to this kind of thing, and the Dired code offers you all of the building blocks you need to do this easily -- in particular, `dired-get-marked-files`. See the code for the many `dired-do-*` commands defined in `dired-aux.el`, for examples.

For example:

```el
(defun my-dired-do-stats (&optional arg)
  "Do stats for the marked files."
  (interactive "P")
  (dolist (file  (dired-get-marked-files nil arg))
    (my-stats-function file))))
```

Comment: Or `define-derived-mode` inheriting from `dired-mode` if you want to deviate from it somewhat more significantly.